# jQuery : Change var when clicking

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, reset, var

I have a circular progress bar and want to update it (and its span with the values) when clicking on a div. The click should add the value of an input to a var. I have created a small preview of this. My problem is the var doesn't seem to change when clicking. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```js
var calories = 1000;
var total = 2500;
var percentage = calories / total;
var pluscal = $('#quantity').val();
var span = $('#today-progress span').html(calories + '/' + total);


/* setInterval(() => {
  calories = 0
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
var today = new Date().getTime();
localStorage.setItem("today", today); */


$('#confirm-svg').click(function() {
  calories = calories + pluscal;
  $('#today-progress').circleProgress();
});


$('#today-progress').circleProgress({
  value: percentage,
  size: 300.0,
  startAngle: -1.57,
  thickness: 'auto',
  fill: {
    gradient: ['#CE6363', '#B23939'],
  },
  emptyFill: '#D6A0A0',
  animation: {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'circleProgressEasing'
  },
  animationStartValue: 0.0,
  reverse: false,
  lineCap: 'round',
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#today-progress {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#today-progress span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  float: right;
  fill: #000;
}

svg:active {
  fill: red;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
<div id="today-progress">
  <span></span>
</div>

<form>
  Quantity (between 1 and 1000):
  <input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="1000">
</form>

<div id="confirm-svg">
  <svg id="confirm-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 305.002 305.002" style="enable-background:new 0 0 305.002 305.002;"
  xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M152.502,0.001C68.412,0.001,0,68.412,0,152.501s68.412,152.5,152.502,152.5c84.089,0,152.5-68.411,152.5-152.5    S236.591,0.001,152.502,0.001z M152.502,280.001C82.197,280.001,25,222.806,25,152.501c0-70.304,57.197-127.5,127.502-127.5    c70.304,0,127.5,57.196,127.5,127.5C280.002,222.806,222.806,280.001,152.502,280.001z"
        />
        <path d="M218.473,93.97l-90.546,90.547l-41.398-41.398c-4.882-4.881-12.796-4.881-17.678,0c-4.881,4.882-4.881,12.796,0,17.678    l50.237,50.237c2.441,2.44,5.64,3.661,8.839,3.661c3.199,0,6.398-1.221,8.839-3.661l99.385-99.385    c4.881-4.882,4.881-12.796,0-17.678C231.269,89.089,223.354,89.089,218.473,93.97z"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

(JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vf1gqsL4/1/))
Also, if it's possible I'd like to reset this var (calories) to 0 every 24 hours, you can see my pitiful attempt at this in a comment in js code.. If you can help me with that, it would be awesome too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the variables that were declared at the top every time you click the submit checkmark button.

Also, you should parseInt the value from the input box and you should call `circleProgress()` with all the settings necessary to redraw the circle stuff. The way you have right now, there are no settings.

Something like the following to get you started: [See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vf1gqsL4/6/)

```
$('#confirm-svg').click(function() {
  // Every time you click, you should parse the integer from the input,
  // then add that to the sum of calories.
  calories = calories + parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
  percentage = calories / total; 

  // Then you have to update the calories mark with the new value of calories
  $('#today-progress span').html(calories + '/' + total);
  // Then you have to redraw the circle stuff
  drawCircle()
});

function drawCircle() {
  $('#today-progress').circleProgress({
    value: percentage,
    size: 300.0,
    startAngle: -1.57,
    thickness: 'auto',
    fill: {
      gradient: ['#CE6363', '#B23939'],
    },
    emptyFill: '#D6A0A0',
    animation: {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'circleProgressEasing'
    },
    animationStartValue: 0.0,
    reverse: false,
    lineCap: 'round',
  });
}

// Draw the initial circle
drawCircle();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked, I totally forgot the parseInt necessity..I added the span change update in the function drawCircle so there's only this function to call, but you solved it, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I wanted to accept your answer, but there is still the reset issue not fixed and if I accept it, no one's going to look at it, I'll accept it later if that's ok with you

Comment: @MaëlleJumel you can set a timeout for it to reset after 24 hours, but who is going to be waiting at your website 24 hours just for that to reset? If you are talking about permanent storage, that something entirely different and requires a backend database to maintain your data. The frontend is only concerned with the view and should receive data from somewhere else. It merely renders the data in a nice and friendly format.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle I added...

```
setInterval(() => {
    calories = 0;
    $('#today-progress').circleProgress();
}, 5000);
```

And it reset it every 5 seconds with the animation.  Disregarding the 5 seconds vs 24 hours, is this what you are after?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! It is kind of what I'm looking for but the var isn't setting back to 0? Also do you know if, with your code, the value would stay the same when refreshing, meaning the interval wouldn't start again?

Comment: @MaëlleJumel I think you are missing some basic concepts of web development. Nothing is permanent in the frontend, if you refresh the page it will go back to its initial state. Yes, you can try using local storage, but that is only local to the user of the app. To have "true permanent storage", you need to learn the concept of a backend and databases. All you see in the frontend is nothing but a friendly rendition of data that is received from somewhere else. In short, the frontend always first fetches some data from a server and then displays it in a human friendly format.

Comment: Yes I'd like to make it "true permanent storage", I need to learn about that. Sorry I'm indeed not an expert at all, I've only learned the main stuff through creating drafts of websites (HTML/CSS/JS) but never an actual site with a domain and actual data @nbkhope

Answer (score 1):

To answer your reset calories variable question,
Assumning you want to reset it every 10am,
Try:

```
var now = new Date();
    var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) - now;
    if (millisTill10 < 0) {
         millisTill10 += 86400000; // it's after 10am, try 10am tomorrow. 10 is my number
    }
    setTimeout(function(){var calories = 0;}),
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Although this is like the other answers right, it will only work if you don't reload the page?

Comment: Yeah. How exactly do you intent your application to work?

Comment: You can create a simple PHP script that will take care of the timing. This will take care of refreshing the page. Le'me know if you need help with it.

Comment: I'm going to look into this PHP thing, thank you. I'll let you know if I'm lost :)

Comment: Cool. All the best